# datetime format exception occurring when reading from API

Tags: c#, datetime

I have c# code that reads data from an API and then ultimately inserts into a db.

Everything was working fine, then suddenly one day the code decided it didn't like the date format anymore, and fails giving me this error:

> System.FormatException: 'The DateTime represented by the string is not
>   supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.'

Here is the snippet of code that fails:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(readStream.ReadToEnd());

foreach (var apiData in obj)
{
     DateTime resdate = Convert.ToDateTime(apiData.time);
}
```

In this image I pinned the apiData.time so you can see the date format. 
[image]

So how the heck do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: As the API returns a wrong value (24:30 is not a valid time) you should change apiData.time before converting it to a DateTime.. apiData.time = apiData.time.Replace(" 24:"," 00"); might help in your case...

Comment: Sorry.. ```apiData.time = apiData.time.Replace(" 24:"," 00:");``` of course ;-) Actually you should also check if you have to add a day in your special case.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, that time is not valid! Duh, I should have seen that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might need to change the `Convert.ToDateTime()` method you are using. You can try to use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) to handle the Globalization issue you are seeing:

```
resdate = DateTime.ParseExact(apiData.time, "yyyy-MM-ddT24:mm:ssK", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Unsure of the exact format you want, but that can be modified by changing the `"yyyy-MM-ddT24:mm:ssK"` formatting string. You can find a list of supported formats [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

If the `DateTime` is not in a valid format -- indicated by `24:30` part of the object -- you can use the `DateTime.TryParse()` method to check this record before entering it into your database:

```
DateTime dateValue;

// check if DT is in valid format
if (DateTime.TryParse(apiData.time, out dateValue))
{
    // case: valid date
    // dateValue is the parsed value of apiData.date
} else {
    // case: invalid date
}
```